# Manipulating while filtering

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I asked a question but did not get any proper answers:

[A beginner's attempt on image filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861907/a-beginners-attempt-on-image-filtering)

I am stuck with this. What are we supposed to manipulate in Gaussian Blur?

I have an `IplImage *img` which I want to blur, but I am Completely Clueless about which part of the structure I need to modify to pull off the algorithm?

I can't manipulate `img->imageData`, it is just a character pointer. What do I need to manipulate to generate the blur effect? Any changes to `img->imageData` modifies `RBG` values.

This is what the data structure looks like:

[Image data structure](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00041000000000000000)

Comment: Your other question didn't get answers quickly enough so you decided to create a duplicate question?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Sir i did not want to create a duplicate question. I thought i did not frame my query properly in the previous question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cvSmooth` function is used for Gaussian (and other types of) blurring.  You can read all about it (and all the other functions in the library) in the [OpenCV API](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/index.html).

If you insist on doing smoothing yourself (in the case you really want to know about filtering, or you just like to re-invent the wheel), then you need a basic understanding of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and manipulating the `IplImage` structure.

If you're "Completely Clueless" about something so trivial, I recommend that you invest into a copy of an OpenCV textbook.  I recommend [this one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do) -- once you make it through the first 4-5 chapters, you should be able to handle the majority of lower level image processing tasks.

Good luck.